# Angularjs Modal - how to set modal content dynamically when modal is open

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, modal-dialog

How to set new value to modal content when modal is open/active?

Here is the sample code.

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log, $timeout) {
    $scope.test = "test variable"
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        test: function () {
          return $scope.test;
        }
      }
    });

$timeout( function(){
            $scope.test = "Hello World!";
        }, 5000 );


};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, test) {

  $scope.test = test;
  $scope.$watch('test',function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.test = test;
  });
};
```

In parent controller, i init the modal 1st with "test variable" and after timeout(5 seconds), i want the modal variable change to "Hello World" without close the modal.

can test [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/f1zhkWH6aEtZDoKv8egO?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can directly bind controller scope to modal something like

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      scope: $scope
    });
```

[Here is working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HsxDz4v20WehXJrWEY90?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

Use $timeout function inside ModaInstanceCtrl and then change the scope value of variable accordingly. Here is the sample code:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
    $scope.test = "test variable"
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      scope: $scope,
      resolve: {
        test: function () {
          return $scope.test;

        }
      }
    });
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, $timeout, test) {

    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.test = "variable" 
    }, 2000);

};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/f1zhkWH6aEtZDoKv8egO?p=preview

Comment: I think `scope: $scope` is not needed for the purpose of this example, and don't think it should be recommended as a default, so may I suggest to remove it or comment it out from this example.